# React render using lodash _.forOwn function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, render, forown

```
render() {    
  return (
    <SettingPanel>
      {!loading && _.forOwn(accessLogs, function(groupedLogs, date) {
        console.log(date);
        console.log(groupedLogs);
        console.log("=====");
        return <DayLog date={date} accessLogs={groupedLogs} />;
      })}
    </SettingPanel>
  );
}
```

This code is generating this clientside error for me:

```
warning.js:33 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `SettingPanel`.
    in SettingPanel (created by AccessLogsPanel)
    in AccessLogsPanel (created by inject-AccessLogsPanel-with-teamStore-accessLogsStore)
    in inject-AccessLogsPanel-with-teamStore-accessLogsStore (created by TeamSecurity)
```

---

Any glaring mistake I made? I just want to render a `<DayLog />` component for each key in `accessLogs`.

Comment: How does your SettingPanel component look like

Comment: In `SettingsPanel` I render `{children}` in between a div wrapper.

Comment: Could you also paste the code for `SettingPanel`, does it have PropTypes defined? Also is it `SettingsPanel` or `SettingPanel`

Answer (score 2):

Lodash's `_.forOwn()` returns an object, which React can't render. Instead of `_.forOwn()` use [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#map):

```
render() {    
  return (
    <SettingPanel>
      {!loading && _.map(accessLogs, function(groupedLogs, date) {
        return <DayLog date={date} accessLogs={groupedLogs} />;
      })}
    </SettingPanel>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since lodash `_.forOwn` returns an object you might need to create an array instead for the `children` prop to be valid.

Something like this might work:

```
render() {
  const logs = Object.keys(accessLogs).reduce((result, date) => {
    const groupedLogs = accessLogs[date];
    result.push(<DayLog date={date} accessLogs={groupedLogs} />);
    return result;
  }, []);
  return (
    <SettingPanel>
      {!loading && logs}
    </SettingPanel>
  );
}
```